# how can i convert boost::array to boost::shared_ptr

Tags: c++, arrays, boost, shared-ptr

```
boost::array<uint8_t,1000> buffer;
ByteBuffer b((boost::shared_ptr<uint8_t>)buffer.data(), buffer.size());
```

well, the cast kinda works but when the debuger go to the end of the method it gives me an error so i was wondering if there aonther way to cast/convert it to make it works!

Comment: That is wrong on several levels and will never work. What is it you are trying to do?

Answer (score 3):

This makes no sense. You are attempting to "hack" around errors by applying arbitrary casts.

`shared_ptr` is a wrapper around a pointer to dynamically-allocated objects. It manages their dynamic lifetime.

`array` is a wrapper around an array with *automatic storage duration*. The `uint8_t` array it wraps is not a dynamically-allocated block of memory.

So, this conversion is completely inappropriate and will result in Undefined Behaviour... and that's even if you can get it to compile. In general, use C++ casts like `static_cast`, which error out on improper conversions like this in a way that C casts do not.

(It's tempting to use C casts so that it "just works", but in reality what you're usually doing is burying your head in the sand and singing "ahhh" while your code crumbles into nonsense.)

Why not just:

```
ByteBuffer b(buffer.data(), buffer.size());
```

If `ByteBuffer` really requires a `shared_ptr` as input, then you're going to have to either store the data in a `shared_ptr`-controlled *dynamic* block of memory to begin with, or copy it into one for this operation.

Comment: @Tomalak Geret'kal
`boost::shared_ptr<uint8_t> buf(buffer.data());
   ByteBuffer b(buf, buffer.size());`
it still giving me the error `Experssion: BLOCK_TYPE_IS_VALID(pHead->nBlockUse)`

Comment: @Mixed: Yes, because, as explained above, it's an invalid and nonsensical conversion.

Comment: @Tomalak Geret'kal **If ByteBuffer really requires a shared_ptr as input, then you're going to have to either store the data in a shared_ptr** , yes it is how can i do that i mean to store the data in a shared_ptr

Comment: You could still use a shared_ptr with a custom deallocator that does nothing but that's only good while the scope of the pointer exists. This possibility exists specifically for cases where a 3rd party lib would require a shared_ptr with a noop custom deallocator as input combined stack/local variable as the input to the call.

Comment: @MixedCoder: That's not what I said; you only copied half of my sentence, and then just ignored the rest of it. I said a _dynamic block of memory_ that's controlled by a `shared_ptr`. Really, mixing `shared_ptr` with any kind of array (dynamic or otherwise) is a complete recipe for disaster, and I find it **highly** unlikely that the library in question requires this.

Comment: I agree with Tomalek. The class ByteBuffer should maybe be redesigned to take a shared_array<uint8_t> instead of a shared_ptr<uint8_t>.

Comment: Of course, we don't know what `ByteBuffer` does, so commenting on its semantics is guesswork.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you are trying to do. If you want to create a reference counted block of 1000 uint8_t, then create a shared array:

```
boost::shared_array<uint8_t>(new uint8_t[1000])
```

Answer (score 0):

The only way to have that work is the following. And I think it is a VERY BAD IDEA:

```
boost::array<uint8_t,1000> buffer;
ByteBuffer b(boost::shared_ptr<uint8_t>(buffer.data(), [](uint8_t*){}), buffer.size()); // Note that the deleter does nothing.
```

Comment: Whilst this code works, it's not an appropriate solution to the question and I feel that it's actually a dangerous suggestion (though you do admit that it's probably a bad idea!)

Comment: Specifically, this is only safe if you can guarantee that `buffer` will stay in scope as long as any copy of the shared pointer is still in use. In general, this is very hard to guarantee; but using `shared_ptr` as it is intended (i.e. controlling the life of a dynamically allocated object, or other resource that needs releasing after use) will solve that exact problem for you.

Answer (score 0):

What is ByteBuffer? Is that a standard library class, a class from elsewhere, or one you wrote yourself? What is the declaration, what type does it expect on instantiation?

It sounds to me like a class for managing a chunk of raw memory -- but boost:array or shared_array ALREADY does that. What do you actually want to acheive?

I think either:

- ByteBuffer expects a raw pointer (char*) to existing memory, and you mistakenly use shared_ptr (shared_ptr only applies to single an object allocated by 'new')
- or, You don't need ByteBuffer at all, everything you need can be done by a boost::array
- or, ByteBuffer expects a shared_ptr to an object of some sort rather than an array
- or, ByteBuffer really does want a shared_ptr to an array, but this is almost certainly broken. It is *possible* to do this, but (a) casting doesn't do it, that just says "this memory, interpret it as if it's another sort of object, even if that just puts garbage data in" (unless the two types have an inbuild conversion, which array and shared_ptr don't) and (b) it's weird and fiddly and I honestly don't believe for a second that ByetBuffer expects this, or if it does, that it's worth using.